# Add Column to Databricks Table Syntax Error

Tags: sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I am trying to add a column based on a case when statement mapping status to status names. This is in Databricks, and i'm wondering if i'm having an issue with permissions or if my syntax is off somewhere. A similar statement worked in SQL server.

```
    ALTER TABLE dbo.table
    ADD status_name as (CASE        WHEN status = '0' THEN 'Pink'
                                    WHEN status = '9' THEN 'Green'
                                    WHEN status = '8' THEN 'Blue'
                                    WHEN status = '2' THEN 'Red'
                                    ELSE 'Other'
                                    END);
```

This is the error message I am getting:

Error in SQL statement: ParseException:
no viable alternative at input 'ALTER TABLE db.table\nADD status_name'(line 2, pos 4)

Anyone know where i'm going wrong here? Shouldn't the syntax be identical between data-bricks and sql server? The table names are different in Databricks.

Comment: Definitely not a permissions issue it's a syntax problem. Where is your table located? on Databricks or SQL Server? `ADD COLUMN

This clause is not supported for JDBC data sources.

Adds one or more columns to the table, or fields to existing columns in a Delta Lake table.`

Comment: The table is in Databricks. If I query the db by referencing the db.table, it works. But suddenly when I try to add a column it won’t work. So i’m judt trying to see if there’s a syntax difference between databricks and sql server or if it’s something else… looking like i’ll just have to ask a coworker haha

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you missed COLUMN in your statement.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.table
ADD **COLUMN** status_name
```